# Total variation defined as Integral

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\phi: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ a function absolutely continuous with derivative continuous. Show that $TV(\phi, [a,b])=T_a^{b}(\phi)=\displaystyle\int_a^{b} \left|\phi'(x)\right|dx.$

Hello, my Professor solved this problem separate in cases. Furthermore, the idea of proof consists in show that $T_a^{b}(\phi)\ge \displaystyle\int_a^{b} \left|\phi'(x)\right|dx$ and $T_a^{b}(\phi)\le \displaystyle\int_{a}^b \left|\phi'(x)\right|dx.$ However, I'm not sure if this is correct... Can help me? Thanks.

Comment: How do you define the total variation? What you wrote seems almost tautological, so how you would prove that will heavily depend on the exact definitions. And what is it you are not sure about, exactly?

Comment: Hi, for the definition we have $T_a^{b}(\phi)=\sup\{V(\phi, \mathcal{P}): \mathcal{P}\, \text{is partition of}\, [a,b]\}$. Furthermore, $V(\phi, \mathcal{P})=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|.$ We have that $TV(\phi, [a,b])<\infty$.

Comment: What about the other question? What are you unsure about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't even need $\phi$ to have a continuous derivative. Suppose $\phi$ is an AC funciton on $[a,b]$. Then $\phi$ is differentiably a.e., $\phi'\in L^1([a,b])$, and the fundamental theorem of calculus applies. Define $F$ on $[a,b]$ by $F(x) = T_a^x(\phi).$

It's easy to prove that $F(x)\leq \int_a^x|\phi'(t)|\,dt$. For any partition $\{y_i\}$ of $[a,x]$,
$$
\sum_i|\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})| \leq \sum_i \int_{y_{i-1}}^{y_i}|\phi'(t)|\,dt = \int_a^x|\phi'(t)|\,dt.
$$
As the supremum of all these sums over partitions, $F(x) \leq \int_a^x|\phi'(t)|\,dt$.

For the other direction, first We claim that $F$ is AC on $[a,b]$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta >0$ such that for any finite set $\{[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\}$ of disjoint intervals in $[a,b]$ with $\sum(\beta_i-\alpha_i) <\delta$, $\sum|f(\beta_i) - f(\alpha_i)| \leq \epsilon$. For any partition $\{y_{ij}\}$ of $\{[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\}$ (in the sense that each $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ is partitioned),
$$
\sum_i\sum_j(y_{ij} - y_{i,j-1}) = \sum_i(\beta_i - \alpha_i) <\delta.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_i\sum_j|\phi(y_{ij}) - \phi(y_{i,j-1})| \leq \epsilon.
$$
But $\sum_i(F(\beta_i) - F(\alpha_i))$ is the supremum of these sums, so $\sum_i(F(\beta_i) - F(\alpha_i)) \leq \epsilon$. That means $F$ is AC, and $F(x) = \int_a^x F'(t)\,dt$.

Suppose both $F'$ and $f'$ exists at $t$, and $h>0$. Then
$$
\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h} = \frac{1}{h}T_t^{t+h}(\phi) \geq \left|\frac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h}\right|.
$$
Hence
$$
F'(t) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h} \geq \lim_{h\to 0^+} \left|\frac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h}\right| = |\phi'(t)|.
$$
Therefore,
$$
F(x) \geq \int_a^x|\phi'(t)|\,dt
$$
for all $x\in [a,b]$. Combine the two inequalities, you get
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x|\phi'(t)|\,dt.
$$

Note that we've been tacitly using $T_a^x(\phi) + T_x^b(\phi) = T_a^b(\phi)$. It shouldn't be hard for you to prove this.